# How to copy all the contents of various threaded textframes to another textframe in indesign with javascript?

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I would need to copy all the text, formatting and images to another textframe. I've tried with text but it only copies the first textframe and not all the text from the threaded textframe.

thanks

Comment: I would give you an upvote if you posted some code for what you had already come up with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple solution:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

var page = doc.pages[0];

var frame1 = page.textFrames[0];
var frame2 = page.textFrames[1];

frame1.texts.everyItem().select();
app.copy();

frame2.texts.everyItem().select();
app.paste();
```